# Upload video to youtube error 400 InvalidRequestUriException using GData API

Tags: iphone, gdata-api

I'm trying to post video to youtube from inside of my iPhone application using the GData API. Here is the code I'm using:

```
GDataServiceGoogleYouTube* service = [self youTubeService];
[service setYouTubeDeveloperKey:youtubeAppKey];

NSString *username = service.username;
NSURL *url = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeUploadURLForUserID:username];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.videoPath];
NSString *filename = @"My Cool Video";
NSString *titleStr = @"Title";
GDataMediaTitle *mediaTitle = [GDataMediaTitle textConstructWithString:titleStr];

NSString *categoryStr = @"Comedy";
GDataMediaCategory *mediaCategory = [GDataMediaCategory mediaCategoryWithString:categoryStr];
[mediaCategory setScheme:kGDataSchemeYouTubeCategory];

NSString *descStr = @"Description";
GDataMediaDescription *mediaDesc = [GDataMediaDescription textConstructWithString:descStr];

NSString *keywordsStr = @"iOS";
GDataMediaKeywords *mediaKeywords = [GDataMediaKeywords keywordsWithString:keywordsStr];

GDataYouTubeMediaGroup *mediaGroup = [GDataYouTubeMediaGroup mediaGroup];
[mediaGroup setMediaTitle:mediaTitle];
[mediaGroup setMediaDescription:mediaDesc];
[mediaGroup addMediaCategory:mediaCategory];
[mediaGroup setMediaKeywords:mediaKeywords];
[mediaGroup setIsPrivate:isPrivate];

NSString *mimeType = [GDataUtilities MIMETypeForFileAtPath:self.videoPath
                                           defaultMIMEType:@"video/mp4"];

GDataEntryYouTubeUpload *entry = [GDataEntryYouTubeUpload uploadEntryWithMediaGroup:mediaGroup
                                                                               data:data
                                                                           MIMEType:mimeType
                                                                               slug:filename];

GDataServiceTicket *ticket = [service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:entry
                                                      forFeedURL:url
                                                        delegate:self
                                               didFinishSelector:@selector(uploadTicket:finishedWithEntry:error:)];
[self setUploadTicket:ticket];
```

And I'm having this response:

serviceBase: objectFetcher:GTMHTTPUploadFetcher 0x48af0a0 (https://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumable/feeds/api/users/myCoolMail@gmail.com/uploads?upload_id=heregoesidiremoved) failedWithStatus:400 data:GData`InvalidRequestUriException`Exception message unavailable

I've tried Google sample code and had the same result. I used device and Simulator (5.0). I've tried prepared video as long as the recorded from iPhone one.
I created the Project in the google API section and got an application key.

Please, help me find the solution of the problem!

Comment: same is the case with my code. if you have working demo of upload video to youtube please share it with me. thnks. my id is ravi.parmar@yahoo.in

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was here:

```
NSString *username = service.username;
NSURL *url = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeUploadURLForUserID:username];
```

Don't know why is that, but I've changed the userID from "username" to kGDataServiceDefaultUser and the thing started working. So simple and so odd, but it did the trick.

Correct code:

```
NSURL *url = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeUploadURLForUserID:kGDataServiceDefaultUser];
```